# STM32 G07 Full Duplex SPI (Master + Slave) - Rx Array on Master is shifted

Tags: stm32, spi, dma

I have designed a PCB with an STM32 G070CB MCU (@64 MHz) on it to test the performance of LVDS ICs (TI SN65LVDS...). I am using both SPIs of the G070, one is used as Master, the other one as slave. The original purpose was to examine different cable types and length to see now good and at which SPI speed I could connect two PCBs with SPI (over LVDS). I am using two of these PCBs, one is the Master, the other one is the Slave. So each PCB has only to handle one SPI, the other one is idle. The Hardware-Connection is 4-wire SPI with CSn, MISO, MOSI and SCK. All four signals are converted into LVDS on the master and converted back from LVDS on the slave.

[image: Test Setup]

I am using the STM32 HAL Functions for SPI Transmit + Receive in DMA mode. For easier debugging, I am sending an array with 20 bytes. The Master sends out the numbers 0 - 19, but the last element in the array is replaced by a Tx Counter, which is incremented on each transmission, the Slave sends back the numbers 19 - 0 where the first element in the array is replaced by a transmission counter.

```
// simplified code: Master
uint8_t dataM[20];
uint8_t dataS[20]; 
uint16_t SPIDataSz = 20;  
HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(hSPI, dataM, dataS, SPIDataSz);

// simplified code: Slave
uint8_t dataM[20];
uint8_t dataS[20]; 
uint16_t SPIDataSz = 20;  
HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA(hSPI, dataS, dataM, SPIDataSz);
// TX Pointer: dataS, RX Pointer: dataM
```

Furthermore, both PCBs are also connected via UART, the Slave tells the Master, when it is ready, the Master won't start the transmission before the Slave sends its start command via UART. The Master is using normal DMA Mode for Rx and Tx, the Slave either normal or circular.

The Transmission Frequency on the Master is defined by a timer. At the moment I am testing (typically) with one transmission very 100 ms, but I also got stable connections with a transmission Frequency of 5 kHz. The SPI Clock Frequencies vary, I got stable communication with clock rates up to 8 MHz (with 1.2 m of CAT5 Cable), but the issue I am describing is independent from the SPI Clock rate. It occurs at 1 MHz as well as at 8 MHz.

When the Slave uses normal DMA, the communication is OK. I can debug the Master as well as the Slave, and I can see the transferred data look like expected. This means: After the >>HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback()<<occurs, the next transmission is started with >>HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA (…)<< on the slave.

The issues come up, when I set the Slave to circular DMA and using “double buffer technique”. The idea behind that was to save at least some of the overhead of the >>HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA (…)<< function, and just react on the both HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback(...) and HAL_SPI_TxRxHalfCpltCallback(...) callbacks.

The issue is: the array received on the master is shifted by 3 or 4 bytes, constantly and stable. If I restart the slave by pressing the Reset Button (NRST -> low), both boards resync (via UART) and it works as intended. The arrays on both (Slave and Master) are as intened, the communication is stable – even for long periods.

Due to several tests I am pretty sure, it’s not an issue with the SPI Clock speed. The Communication is stable at 1 MHz, as well as 8 MHz. It’s not an issue caused by the Transmission Frequency, the data are shifted at 10 Hz as well as at 5 kHz. There is a delay of 100 ms on the Slave after calling >>HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA (…)<< before signaling to the master (via UART), that the slave is ready and of course I check the output of this function call. The Master is only triggered by the slave, when the return value of >>HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_DMA (…)<< is “HAL_OK”.

My suspicion is: With the first event of CSn going from high to low on the Slave (NSS Hardware input), the DMA Controller on the Slave is “late” for some reason I don’t understand. But it’s only late for the data it transmits to the Master (TX-buffer), but NOT for the data, it receives from the Master.

There is a "huge delay" of a couple of Microseconds between the CSn line going down and the first clock tick, but the fact that the Slave receives the data from the Master correctly already indicateds that this is also not an issue.

Has anyone an explanation:

- why the SPI Tx DMA on the Slave misses the first 3-4 Clock ticks in the
  first transmission while the Rx DMA works correctly? Afterwards it is in sync ...
- why it would (always) sync correctly when I press the reset button on the slave –
  there is no difference in Code ?!
- why it only misses the Clock ticks in DMA circular mode, but NOT in normal mode?

Any help would be highly appreciated, after 3 days of testing and debugging I am running out of options. One option would be of course to kick out all the HAL Functions - which are pretty bulky - and go to Bare Metal Programming or the LL drivers, but obviously this would also mean a major setback in the project and I'd like to avoid that if I can.